# PROTRACTOR - Failed: element.all is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a problem to use the element.all function. My guess is, that it has problems with an id. I know an id should be used one time only, but I am testing the software only and have no possibility to change this id to a class. So maybe there is a solution to get it with element.all and then process with the index function.

```
let buttons = element.all(by.id('wanted id'));
```

When this code snippet is invoked. It says:

```
element.all is not a function.
```

When I use only element it works, but I cannot use the index function.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You didn't close parenthesis in `buttons`.

Comment: oh sorry, in the original snippet they are closed. Otherwise protractor wouldn't start.

Comment: hmm this piece of code looks correct. Can you paste some more code?

Comment: Please see my answer below. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by using all, without element before.

```
all(by.id('wanted id')).then( elem => {
      ...
});
```

Comment: I dont understand how this works for you?  `all` is a method on the `ElementArrayFinder` prototype.  Also, for what it's worth, you could have used `by.css`, i.e. `element.all(by.css('#my-id'));`

Comment: I also very confused, only possible reason is your code did reassign like `global.all = element.all`, In protractor official API, there is only `element.all` no `all`

Comment: You're both right. In the documentations there you can only find element.all, which didn't do the job. Why it is working I can't tell you. But it works. 

@Gunderson I will try it with the css as well.